# Vegas, Monte Carlo multi integration, QCD

Tags: monte-carlo

To do some calculation on QCD on Lattice, I needed a Monte Carlo multi integration. I wrote a a C++ program according to what I understood from the paper “ Lepage (1978) “  A New Algorith For Adaptive Multidimensional Integration” SLAC_Pub_1839 November 1976” The results I got, however, were not accurate, so I copied the written program from the books: a) Numeerical Recipies in C and  b) Numeerical Recipies in C  Examples. The program is running for 4 days on My PC with Intel Core 2 Due, @ 2.9 GHz. My question is from anyone who has experience on Vegas algorithm that this long running is normal or my program is in a non-ending loop. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested your algorithm against functions with known anti-derivatives? If the algorithm is not the focus of your research, I would suggest using a pre-existing (read: tested) library. In particular, GNU Scientific Library and the CUBA Library both have VEGAS implemented.

Answer (score 2):

I used VEGAS some time ago to calculate the hadronic cross section using partonic cross section and parton distributions and none of my calculations lasted that long. Around ~10-20min at most. I would go with the precompiled CUBA libraries. There are four different algorithms Cuhre, Divonne, Suave and Vegas, consult with the manual/paper for more information and then choose the one fits best at your needs.